# What is JDBC (Java DataBase Connectivity)?

Tags: java, jdbc

What is JDBC and where can I start learning about?

I know it's a way to access databases with Java, but what problems does it solve? Is it an ORM (or does it try to be)? Does it abstract away differences between databases, at the syntax level? What does it do? and what does it not do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JDBC is a driver that allows you to access database.  It provides you with a very raw way to access the database using SQL.  Its primary function is to allow you (the user) to run SQL commands on the database.  It is not an ORM and never will be.  The sun website http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/ has a nice tutorial for JDBC. If you are interested in a ORM try http://www.hibernate.org/.

Answer (score 4):

No, JDBC isn't an ORM. It's the [Java Database Connectivity](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/index.jsp) API and basically it provides a database-agnostic access layer with a provider model (so that new database drivers can be added easily). Vendors can add more functionality for specific database features if they wish, but developers can ignore those features if they wish to work with multiple databases.

There's no mapping involved - just modeling for connections (and pools), prepared statements, stored procedures, result sets etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Database Connectivity (JDBC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jdbc) is an API for the Java programming language that defines how a client may access a database. It provides methods for querying and updating data in a database. JDBC is oriented towards relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC - Java Database Connectivity

JDBC is a way to connect your database to your java development through a driver for each type of relational database (Oracle, MySql, MariaDB, AWS, ...)!

The JDBC can be downloaded in your java project using MAVEN in the Project!
From there  you can pull the JDBC dependency for you project in the arquive POM of MAVEN.
Dependency link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

`Maven:`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>NameId</groupId>
    <artifactId>NameProjectJava</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Package</name>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Instance database in the Java with JDBC:

```
public class DB {

Connection con;
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
private Statement stmt;
private ResultSet rs;
static private DB instance;

private DB(String host, String user, String password, int port, String dbName) throws SQLException {
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(dbName);
    dataSource.setServerName(host);
    dataSource.setUser(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setPort(port);
    dataSource.setServerTimezone("UTC");
}

private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return this.dataSource.getConnection();
}

public static DB getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        try {
            instance = new DB("localhost", "root", null, 3306, "group3_hr");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've practically answered your own question.

It provides a common interface for accessing databases, which means that regardless of the nuances of individual databases, or how they are implemented, your API calls are the same. It is not an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is a set of java interfaces classes which connect your application with any relational database management system.